# How to periodically remove data from Apache Solr?

Tags: solr, solrj

I am using Apache Solr 4.3.1 as a repository for storing and indexing the data . Now, One of the field is related to the data of posting of data. I want to update the repository by deleting those entries which are older than 30 days and keeping only relevant data on temporal basis.

I have a web application based on Solrj which is interacting with Solr server for fetching the search results. Should I add a scheduled thread for deleting data from Solr server after 30 days or Solr provides a functionality to automatically remove the data after specific time period?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solr does not do that automatically.

You can add a field timestamp which defaults to NOW when you insert the Records.

```
<field name="timestamp" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NOW" />
```

And you can have a job which runs periodically to clean up the data.
The 30 days can be easily add to the delete query `fq=timestamp:[* to NOW/DAY-30DAYS]` (Check for the exact syntax)